# Azure - Finding resources I am an owner of in another azure account

Tags: azure

I am just getting started with azure, (working with IoT hubs) hopefully this isn't too dumb a question - I didn't find it by searching on here...

Anyway  - I have had a play about with an IoT Hub instance owned by my azure account (started on the 1 month free trial, then today I also added an MSDN member free benefit)

Now basic connectivity from the device I'm programming to my own IoT-hub instance is happening, I want to work with the IoT-hub instance in the account of my employer, so all data goes into their system from now on.

They've set me up as an owner on their side for their IoThub I want to connect to (I have a screenshot that shows I'm an owner for the resource in question - attached) but when I go into my azure dashboard I can't seem to find any way to show me this resource.

So, how do I find this?
[image: My employer's Azure admin panel screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try looking in "subscriptions" to see if your employers is listed. You can also click on your profile name to see if there are other directories listed that you can browse within for resources.  Another option is that when you set up your deployment, your employers subscription will be an option you can select to deploy into.

Comment: AHA! THANK YOU! 

I clicked on my name, and there it is - the ability to swap between my directory and my employer's directory... 

I hadn't seen anything about directories before, but I guess it makes sense to have resources in another account show up in an entirely different place to the resources in my account. (I think it's a bit of a weird place to select between them though, but anyway - thanks so much!)